# v-model in toast-ui editor for vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

toast-ui vue-editor doesn't support v-model to bind the value. What should be done to bind the input value while using toast-ui vue-editor?
I have setup toast-ui:

```
import '@toast-ui/editor/dist/toastui-editor.css';
import { Editor } from '@toast-ui/vue-editor';
export default {
  components: {
    editor: Editor
  }
}
```

```
<editor
    :initialValue="form.explanation"
    height="500px"
    initialEditType="markdown"
    previewStyle="vertical"
    ref="toastuiEditor"
  />
```

I need to bind my form data and save it to database.

Comment: Do you want to read back data or insert data?

Comment: I want to insert data.

Comment: you can reference your editor and invoke its value than you can couple this value to your variable. See their documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/@toast-ui/vue-editor You can search here for `getHtml` it is pretty well documented

Answer (score 0):

A simple and quick solution is to use

```
   @ change = "getHtml"
```

in the data create

```
form: {
       text: ""
}
```

then create a method called

```
getHtml () {
  let html = this. $ refs.toastuiEditor.invoke ('getHtml');

  this.form.text= html;
}
```

where form.text would be who would get the value of the editor

My mother tongue is not English so I apologize if I made a spelling mistake